# Detecting phone number on incoming call ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I heard recently that Apple made it possible to developers to run their app in the background and grab information about the incoming call. Such as the phone number. This has been a security/privacy concern for many years, but I just heard that Apple officially made it possible to do so.

I searched for this question and I saw that it has been asked before some years ago, before the changes were made.

Possible use case would be to run the phone number against a private database and pull information about the caller before answering the call.

Comment: [These search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcallkit%5D+phone+number) should help.

Comment: No, you can't do that.  You can supply a list of numbers in advance to assist with number/name matching and VoIP apps can now integrate with the phone's UI such that they can operate in much the same way as the cellular phone app